# URL Routing in client code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, url-rewriting

I'm trying to figure out how to do URL routing from an ASP Button that uses javascript to navigate. My custom route code is:

```
void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "DocumentByViewerRoute",
        "Document/{documentTitle}",
        "~/Viewer.aspx"
    );
}
```

And my navigation:

```
<h3>View</h3>
    Select a document to view or to search. <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlViewDocument" runat="server"
        ItemType="ArchiveViewer.Models.DocumentMetadata"
        SelectMethod="GetDocumentList" 
        DataTextField="DocumentTitle" DataValueField="DocumentID" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="true" ToolTip="Select a document to view..." 
        Height="40px" style="margin-top: 20px" Width="362px"  >
        <asp:ListItem Text="Please select a document to view..." Value="-1">
        </asp:ListItem>                
    </asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;                       
    <asp:Button ID="btnViewDocument" runat="server" 
        Text="View Selected Document" 
        Height="40px" Width="220px" 
        OnClientClick="var s = $('[id$=ddlViewDocument] option:selected').val(); 
            if (s != -1) { window.open('Viewer.aspx?doc=' + s)};return false;" />
```

How do I re-write the button "**OnClientClick**" method to use URL Routing?

Has anyone encountered this before? I'm at a loss.